# Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: networking, 18.04

I run Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Each time I have a short interuption in my internet connection I get this error.

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

And it never comes back until I restart the server.
What could be the reason for this?

I have tried several suggested sollutions on this forum.
For example:

- Changing from DHCP to static IP and back to DHCP.
- Restart network manager.

I cannot see anything wrong, and it works after restart until my router restarts or I get a temproary internet loss.

Tell me what I should provide and I will provide that.

Comment: So what suggestions have you tried from this forum?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1196371/edit) your question and add more detail of what you actually have tried so that we are not guessing or doubling up work that you have already done.  Thank you!

Comment: To be honest I had this problem for a year and network goes down like 2 times a month. I have tried few things, but dont remember them all.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show interesting log messages.

Answer (score 0):

After some time investigating this I have now found what is causing the problem.

It is OpenVPN that after a connection loss does not reconnect to the VPN server.
That should be a minor problem to fix.

Comment: True. Your question however, was lacking information such as whether you were using `systemd-resolved` or `resolvconf` and what the `nsswitch.conf` contains ...